# I want to update the background color with red if the selected option is not equal the correct option React Js

Tags: reactjs

I've a React component contains radio input buttons that I want to update the background color if the  use click check answer button

I saved the user selections in a state & set the condition rendering when user check the radio button the problem is when user click check answer button in the main APP component the radio input buttons are unchecked & the state linked to the selected answers is set to undefined `your text`

```
export default function SecondPage(props){
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = React.useState()
    const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedAnswer(event.target.checked ? event.target.value : null)
      }
      console.log(selectedAnswer)
    return(
    <div className="radio-toolbar">
            <legend className="quiz">{he.decode(props.question)}</legend>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: props.isSelected ? 'lightgreen' : '' }}>
                <input
                    type="radio" 
                    name={props.id}
                    value={props.choiceOne}
                    checked={selectedAnswer === props.choiceOne}
                    onChange={handleOptionChange}
                />    
                {props.choiceOne}</label>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: props.isSelected && selectedAnswer === props.choiceTwo ? 'red'     : ''}}>
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name={props.id}
                    value={props.choiceTwo}
                    checked={selectedAnswer === props.choiceTwo}
                    onChange={handleOptionChange}
                />
                {props.choiceTwo}
            </label>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: props.isSelected && selectedAnswer === props.choiceThree ? 'red' : ''}}>
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name={props.id} 
                    value={props.choiceThree}
                    checked={selectedAnswer === props.choiceThree}
                    onChange={handleOptionChange}
                />
                {props.choiceThree}
            </label>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: props.isSelected && selectedAnswer === props.choiceFour ? 'red' : ''}}>
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    name={props.id}
                    value={props.choiceFour}
                    checked={selectedAnswer === props.choiceFour}
                    onChange={handleOptionChange}
                />
                {props.choiceFour}
            </label>       
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What does this `SecondPage` indicates and how are you displaying the questions in the `App` component and how you handle the `onClick` event in the `Parent` Component?

Comment: the app has two pages first page has a button when clicked take you to the questions & the questions are brought from an API than I'm saving the API response in a state than iterating over to render & passing it's values to the SecondPage component as a props for the button all it's doing is flipping a state from true to false & I'm using this  state as a ternary for conditional formatting referred in the code by   (props.isSelected)

Comment: Could you share the structure of the API response and the `props` and also the code on how you are iterating over and render the questions from the response?

Comment: the below is an example of API response

Comment: category
: 
"History"
correct_answer
: 
"The Red Baron"
difficulty
: 
"easy"
incorrect_answers
: 
(3) ['The High Flying Ace', 'The Blue Serpent ', 'The Germany Gunner']
question
: 
"What was Manfred von Richthofen&#039;s nickname?"
type
: 
"multiple"

Comment: the below is how I iterate over the API response

Comment: React.useEffect(() =>{
       if(startQuiz === true){
            fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setQuiz(data.results))    
       }
    }, [startQuiz])
    React.useEffect(() =>{
        const correctAnswersArray = quiz.map(answer =>{
            return answer.correct_answer
           })
        setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswersArray)
    },[quiz])
    function check(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        useSubmitAnswers(prevsState => !prevsState)
    }

Comment: const renderQuestions = quiz.map(questions =>{
        return <SecondPage
        key={nanoid()}
        id ={nanoid()}
        question= {questions.question}
        choiceOne= {questions.correct_answer}
        choiceTwo= {questions.incorrect_answers[0]}
        choiceThree= {questions.incorrect_answers[1]}
        choiceFour= {questions.incorrect_answers[2]}
        isSelected = {submitAnswers}
        correctAnswer = {questions.correct_answer}
        />      
    })

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have set a `state` updater function name as `useSubmitAnswers`. It might be considered as a custom hook. So change the name as `setSubmitAnswer`.

```
//App.js
function App() {
  const [startQuiz, setStartQuiz] = React.useState(false);
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);
  const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = React.useState([]);
  const [submitAnswers, setSubmitAnswers] = React.useState(false); // change the state updater function name
  useEffect(() => {
    if (startQuiz === true) {
      const data = [
        {
          category: "History",
          correct_answer: "The Red Baron",
          difficulty: "easy",
          incorrect_answers: [
            "The High Flying Ace",
            "The Blue Serpent ",
            "The Germany Gunner",
          ],
          question: "What was Manfred von Richthofen&#039;s nickname?",
          type: "multiple",
        },
      ];
      setQuiz(data);
    }
  }, [startQuiz]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const correctAnswersArray = quiz.map((answer) => {
      return answer.correct_answer;
    });
    setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswersArray);
  }, [quiz]);

  function check(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitAnswers((prevsState) => !prevsState); //change the state updater function name
  }

  const renderQuestions = quiz.map((questions, index) => {
    return (
      <SecondPage
        key={index}
        id={index}
        question={questions.question}
        choiceOne={questions.correct_answer}
        choiceTwo={questions.incorrect_answers[0]}
        choiceThree={questions.incorrect_answers[1]}
        choiceFour={questions.incorrect_answers[2]}
        isSelected={submitAnswers}
        correctAnswer={questions.correct_answer}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setStartQuiz(true)}>Start Quiz</button>
      <button onClick={check}>Check</button>
      {startQuiz && renderQuestions}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I have tested with the sample data you have given and works fine.